# error in onform submit script when two form submit at same time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

i have a google sheet script and when a form submit it work on somedoing  and then create a new sheet and finally sent sheet as attach of email. it work correct but when two form submit at same time (when second form submit before trigger finish) the email not sent and it not work at all

here is my code:

```
function onSubmit(e){
Logger.log('submit ran');

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


var calculate = ss.getSheets()[2];
var Responses = ss.getSheets()[0];
var report = ss.getSheets()[1];
var report1= ss.getSheets()[3];


var lastRow = Responses.getLastRow();
var copyrange = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

var maxRow1 = report1.getMaxRows();
var lastRow1 = report1.getLastRow();
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
report1.deleteRows(9+count, (172-(9+count)))
SpreadsheetApp.flush();



var email = sB;
var subject = "راید ریپورت "+sa;
var body = se;

var calculate = ss.getSheets()[2];
var Responses = ss.getSheets()[0];
var report = ss.getSheets()[1];


var newSheetid = SpreadsheetApp.create("promoter report "+si,30,60).getId();
var newSheet= DriveApp.getFileById(newSheetid);
DriveApp.getFolderById("1glwG1---------------tW").addFile(newSheet)
newSheet.getParents().next().removeFile(newSheet); 
var sheet = source.getSheets()[3];

var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSheetid);
sheet.copyTo(destination);


var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var  sheet1= destination.getSheetByName("Sheet1").hideSheet();
var sheet1id=sheet1.getSheetId();

SpreadsheetApp.flush();

var pdf = newSheet.getAs('application/pdf')


MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {attachments:[pdf]});
var sf = Responses.getRange(lastRow, 6).setValue("EMAIL_SENT")
SpreadsheetApp.flush();

}
```

Comment: i the script i have line "get last row"

i think when second for submit this code will have error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As you noticed correctly, your codecan run into collisions with simulatenous form submits**

### Why?

Because you perform multiple calls to Spreadsheet Service, which slows your code down significatly, as you can read under [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services).

### What to do?

- Apart from optimizing your code according to the Apps Script Best Practices, **you can use [LockService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock)**
- Lockservice allows you to make sure that only once instance of the script runs at a given time and the subsequent calls "wait in the queue" until the first script execution finishes

### How to use Lockservice?

**Sample based on your code:**

```
function onSubmit(e){
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  // Wait for up to 30 seconds for other processes to finish.
  lock.waitLock(30000);
  Logger.log('submit ran');

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


  var calculate = ss.getSheets()[2];
  var Responses = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var report = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var report1= ss.getSheets()[3];


  var lastRow = Responses.getLastRow();
  var copyrange = Responses.getRange("e2:m2").copyTo(Responses.getRange(lastRow, 5), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();


  var sh = Responses.getRange(lastRow, 8).getValue();



  var cell = calculate.getRange("c2");
  cell.setFormula(sh);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var lastRow = Responses.getLastRow();
  var copyrange = Responses.getRange(lastRow, 5,1, 10).copyTo(Responses.getRange(lastRow, 5),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var sa = Responses.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
  var sB = Responses.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();
  var se = Responses.getRange(lastRow, 5).getValue();
  var sf = Responses.getRange(lastRow, 6).getValue();
  var si = Responses.getRange(lastRow, 9).getValue();

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var rangclear= report1.getRange("a9:z100");
  rangclear.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);

  var count= calculate.getRange("b6").getValue();

  report.getRange("A:Z").copyTo(report1.getRange("A1"));
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  report.getRange("A:Z").copyTo(report1.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var maxRow1 = report1.getMaxRows();
  var lastRow1 = report1.getLastRow();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  report1.deleteRows(9+count, (172-(9+count)))
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var email = sB;
  var subject = "راید ریپورت "+sa;
  var body = se;

  var calculate = ss.getSheets()[2];
  var Responses = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var report = ss.getSheets()[1];


  var newSheetid = SpreadsheetApp.create("promoter report "+si,30,60).getId();
  var newSheet= DriveApp.getFileById(newSheetid);
  DriveApp.getFolderById("1glwG1WF2rgrg54hfh0nJjxgtW").addFile(newSheet)
  newSheet.getParents().next().removeFile(newSheet);

  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = source.getSheets()[3];

  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSheetid);
  sheet.copyTo(destination);


  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var  sheet1= destination.getSheetByName("Sheet1").hideSheet();
  var sheet1id=sheet1.getSheetId();

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var pdf = newSheet.getAs('application/pdf')


  MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {attachments:[pdf]});
  var sf = Responses.getRange(lastRow, 6).setValue("EMAIL_SENT")
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  // Release the lock so that other processes can continue.
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

**Note:**
This code can eb further optimized to run faster

Comment: thank for your useful answer
i want to set   set Confirmation Message in form with some cell in sheet. what should i do?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by confirmation message - do you mean the body of the email? Currently it is set to `Responses.getRange(lastRow, 5).getValue()` which should work as intended provided you soecified the correct cell. If the problem persists I suggest you to make a new post explaining the issue about the confirmation message more in detail and maybe providing a copy of a sample spreadsheet if it helps troubleshooting.